# Number of comments in post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor, data-access-layer

I'm trying to count number of comments from within a post (trying to create some sort of blog) and displaying it in the post's title. Here is some code.

My models:

```
public class Post
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Comment
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int PostID { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
}
```

My controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var dbPosts = (from p in db.Posts
                orderby p.ID descending
                select p).ToList();

    return View(dbPosts);
}
```

My view:

```
@foreach (var post in Model) {
    **@post.Comments.Where(x => x.PostID == post.ID).Count()**

    <h3>@Html.ActionLink(post.Title, "Details", new { id = post.ID })</h3>
    <span class="written">skrevet d. @post.DateTime.ToLongDateString() @post.DateTime.ToShortTimeString() af @post.Author</span>
    <p>@post.Message</p>
    <hr />
}
```

I have marked my error with stars. It gives me an error saying "Value cannot be null."

Anyone who can help me figuring this out?

Kind regards and thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your View in foreach loop you are accessing your post, so just do

```
@post.Comments.Count
```

Also I think your query in Controller might lazy load Comments and they aren't actually included when you send them to your View, so eager load Comments:

```
var dbPosts = db.Posts.Include("Comments").OrderByDescending(p => p.ID).ToList();
```

Comment: That worked pretty well, thanks. Is there a way to do it without Lambda? More like the way I posted, with from, orderby etc? New to the whole MVC world, haven't exactly read up on that part yet. Baby steps here :D

Comment: Ahh too fast.. Just tried var dbPosts = (from p in db.Posts.Include("Comments")... worked aswell

Comment: I wrote in lambdas, because I don't use your querying approach and didn't had any idea where to put .Include :) Please Accept my answer if it has solved your problem. :)

Comment: @KasperHyldalPedersen - Loading the comments in the view violates separation of concerns as it is putting database logic in the view.  Keep your views simple and ensure all the data they need is loaded before they execute.

Comment: Alright :) Lambda seem more easy to read - I guess that will be my next big step in into MVC :) Thanks for the help